# Error when converting varchar(max) to int or float

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, casting

I have a table that stores different info into a value column as `varchar(max)`

I need to be able to extract some of the info from this table, convert it to an integer and average the numbers. I'm running into an issue though when trying to convert.

This does not work:

```
select cast(value as float) as value
from table
```

Can anyone tell me how to properly convert this?

Comment: Good reading on the topic: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/IsNumeric/71512/

Comment: Seriously: read [What's the Point of Using VARCHAR(n) Anymore?](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varchar%28n%29-anymore/) - you shouldn't be using `varchar(max)` too much - only when **really**, absolutely, positively needed (when you **need** more than 8000 characters!)

Comment: thanks for the article, i have no choice for the format of the data in this case (work) so i had to find a way around it.  Thanks again for the assistance on this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably, the problem is that some values are not in a numeric format.  Try this instead:

```
select (case when isnumeric(value) = 1 then cast(value as float) end)
from table
```

This converts all the numbers to float, and puts NULLs in the remaining fields.

If you want to see the values that are causing problems, use this:

```
select value
from table
where isnumeric(value) = 0 and value is not null
```